# Divert A call To the Third User in Android?

Tags: android, service, call

hai i got A project Where i need To Tap A telphone conversation Between To Users let me more Specific if A user call Another user And in his telphone i have installed the Application(Just guess) then that call must go to the 3rd user that has set on that application And he/she can hear what the other two Says is that possible if so how can we implement it?

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately, this is impossible, for obvious security and privacy reasons.

Comment: thank you sir !! i also have that doubt thankz for the replay